# How can I handle popup window safely in selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, popup

I tried many solutions but none of them worked for me. I have one page where it is opening popup and when I try to perform any operation with that popup , it says element not visible.

As per scenario first it takes time to load data so as per below image Popup_1 , And then it shows data as per below image Popup_2.

I am trying to put condition that do not close popup until **I get text "Success:".**

[image]
[image]

**My Code :**

```
 for (String handle : driver.getWindowHandles()) {
    driver.switchTo().window(handle);}


    WebDriverWait waitforEle = new WebDriverWait(driver, 300);
    waitforEle.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath("//*[@id='divc8fff3cf6a']/div[1]/strong")));              
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='modal']/div[1]/a")).click();
```

**HTML code of popup :**

```
<div class="modal fade in" id="modal" style="display: block;"><div class="modal-header"><a class="close" href="#" data-dismiss="modal">×</a><h3>Delete Listings</h3></div><div class="inner"><div id="divc8fff3cf6a">
    <div class="alert alert-success fade in">
  <button class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
  <strong>Success:</strong> 1 products have been queued for removal from Amazon.</div>    <div class="modal-footer">
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-small" onclick="location.reload()">Close</a>    </div>
</div><script>
//<![CDATA[
window.customModal = {"formUUID":"#formfbe89bf4a5","modalUUID":"#divc8fff3cf6a"};
if(typeof window.customModal != 'undefined'){
    $(window.customModal["formUUID"]).on("submit", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            method: "POST",
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            url: $(this).attr("action"),
            before: function(){
                window.modal.close();
                window.loading.show();
            },
            success: function(data, textStatus){
                window.loading.close();
                window.modal.options["content"] = data;
                window.modal.show();
            }
        });

        return false;
    });

    $(".resubmit").on("click", function(e){
        window.modal.close();
        $(window.app[$(this).data("resubmit")]).trigger("submit");
    });
}
//]]>
</script></div></div>
```

Comment: hi, as per loop, if first window is parent, then sure you get exception right?

Comment: This is only one window/popup which is opening. Is there any mistake in that loop then please help to solve. because When I click on close X button of that popup , it works fine so switching seems fine. But not able to manage thing as per question.

Comment: i am expecting that text displaying because of jquery script function just like alert..may be funny did you tried alert command to get text? or javascriptexecutor.. id used in xpath looks like dynamic, i hope used other possible locators also. thanks

Comment: I tried by alert.accept but did not work. Let me try with javascriptexecutor.

Comment: i think there is no ok. so ok does not seems good may be good to try alert.getMessage();

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
if(alert.getText().contains("Success:"))

  alert.dismiss();
```

Comment: Actually it is not alert. When I try as alert. it says `no alert open`.